# How to keep track of current working directory in libfuse

Tags: c, unix, filesystems

I'm implementing file system using [libfuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse). I want to get current working directory of process. I have tried `getcwd` but it always returns `/` root directory.

I want to use it in `symlink` function because first argument is relative path and not full

Comment: Why should your file system care about the first argument? It is just an opaque string to be stored in the special file named by the second argument.

Comment: So I just need to return this first argument in readlink and that's all?

Comment: That's correct.